# Properly written for-loops, normal and inverse, C++ basics

Tags: c++, for-loop

For loops are trivial, right? Well I was wondering about some things, probably because I am a physcist and I havent had proper programming education.
Lets use a the example of having a word string and we want to print the characters seperatelly, and later on reverse order.

Q1) Should we declare a variable for the size assign it and use it or call the size() function of the string, inside the for loop

```
string s = "asdf";
int size = s.size();

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
 cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

//or

```
for (int i = 0; i<s.size(); i++){
 cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

//Q2) If we want to print the characters inversed, which is more proper? Also, do i use new variable size again?

//A)

```
for (int i = size-1; i>= 0; i--){
 cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

//B)

```
for (int i = size; i>= 0; i--){
 cout<<s[i - 1]<<endl;
}
```

//C)

```
for (int i = size - 1; i>= 0; i--){
 cout<<s[i]<<endl;
```

}

//D) 
// I have used this one in case i had to use i for another functionality where it has to be incremented. (ok sure a.size = s.size)

```
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
 cout<<s[size - i - 1]<<endl;
// cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

Q3) Which is the most resource/time friendly?

Q4 and most important) Which is the most proper way for other people to understand and use it and anyway be part of bigger code structure (and not my own personal bullshit)

Q5) Did I forget any other ways?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that it does not really matter, specially with optimisation. It is just a thing of personal preferences.

Comment: I think B for Q2 is bad variant, because you managed to create a bug there while writing an simple example.

Comment: yes you are right, its > 0 , 
thats why I am asking!!

Comment: [Avoid raw loops](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning) (or other [videos of Sean Parent](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzNtM038JuI)). All your examples are better handled with `std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator(std::cout))` (or rbegin and rend).

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer is that you should be using iterators:-):

```
for ( auto current = s.cbegin(), end = s.cend(); current != end; ++ current ) {
    std::cout << *current << std::endl;
}
```

For the reverse order, use `crbegin()` and `crend()` instead of
`cbegin()` and `cend()`.  (And this is C++11.  For earlier
versions, you'll have to spell out the type of the iterator
`std::string::const_iterator` and drop the `c` in the names of
the functions.)

If you do want to do it with indexing (e.g. because you're
iterating simultaneously through several different containers),
the standard idiom for forward iteration would be:

```
for ( int i = 0; i != s.size(); ++ i )...
```

For reverse iteration, I'd use:

```
int i = s.size();
while ( i != 0 ) {
    -- i;
    //  ...
}
```

(Of course, if you're iterating over several containers
simultaneously, you'll have extracted the sizes previously, to
verify that they are equal.  And you'ld use the extracted size,
rather than calling `s.size()` again.)

Comment: for me this inverse loope seems more difficult to understand, and why use a while loop since you know the size already?

Comment: @thahgr It's a question of what your standard idiom is.  The reason for the while loop is because you want the decrementation at the top of the loop, not at the bottom.  (But it _is_ largely a matter of style, and what you are used to.)

Comment: Yes, it really is a matter of style. That's why it's such a nice topic for dispute ;-)

Comment: Why while loop instead of for loop + `(int)s.size()` or (if you are C++ purist) `static_cast<int>(s.size())`?

Comment: @Spook As I said above, it's largely a question of style: I like to be able to use the "natural" end criterion, and still use the index directly in the loop.  Alternatively: you can use `i >= 0` as the criterion (starting the loop at n - 1), or you can use `i - 1` as the index inside the loop.  I don't think that one is necessarily better than the others.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer to your questions: you worry too much. Decent compilers have optimizers, which can do miracles. For instance, once I replaced all `i < sth.size()` with separate variable and it have actually *slown down* my program.

Secondly: why don't you simply run these versions 10^6 times and measure them? There are no simple answers to performance questions.

Thirdly: the general rule is: write code in such way, that it will be the most readable. So, for example, I'd implement the reverse loop in the following way:

```
for (int i = static_cast<int>(str.size()) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    std::cout << str[i] << endl;
```

This code states the intention clearly: I want to go from the end of the string to its beginning. (of course, you may use iterators, which will make the code even more readable).

```
std::for_each(test.rbegin(), test.rend(), [=](char c) { std::cout << c << std::endl; });
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is helpfull!
would you do D) like that? if you had to print one reverse one straightforward ..

Comment: @stefan The initial value of `i` will be `-1`, so the code will work.  But why this is so is far from obvious.  And it's _not_ guaranteed; the actual initial value of `i` in this case is implementation defined.  (I've never heard of an implemntation where it wouldn't be `-1`, but the C standard even explicitly says that it might result in a signal.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Why implementation-defined? Potential choice of unsigned int in favor of int during evaluating - operator? I changed the code to use static_cast to resolve this potential issue.

Comment: @Spook Because the result of `str.size() - 1` will almost certainly be an unsigned integer outside of the range of an `int`, and the results of such a conversion are implementation defined.  (It's not a potential choice of `unsigned int`; unless a `size_t` is smaller than an `int`, it's what the standard requires.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Now it should work correctly. BTW this is weird decision to use unsigned type here. It seem to cause more problems than actual benefits (in reality, it's highly unlikely, that you'll want to keep more than 2G elements in a vector)

Comment: It's clearly a design error today.  It has its roots in history, when there were still a lot of 16 bit machines: you did want `size_t` to be larger than 32K, and requiring it to be more than 16 bits would have a horrible run time impact.  And of course, allowing it to be sometimes signed, sometimes not would make it impossible to write portable code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you certainly want to take the good habits of enabling all warnings and debugging info in your compiler. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve your code till you get no warnings from the compiler.

You also want your code to be readable (either by some colleague working on your source code, or perhaps by yourself in a few months, trying to improve your program.). And you probably want your code to be efficient.

> Q1) Should we declare a variable for the size assign it and use it ?

In other words, is

```
string s = "asdf";
int size = s.size();
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
   cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

preferable to

```
for (int i = 0; i<s.size(); i++){
   cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

In principle, the first variant (computing `size` before the loop) is preferable, since the string size is computed only once, and not at every loop iteration.

In practice, good optimizing compilers (e.g. when compiling with `g++ -O2` using a recent GCC) are able to notice that both forms have the same behavior, and the compiler will often (but not always) optimize both, perhaps even to `for (int i=0; i<4; i++)` (by constant-folding and partially evaluating the string size at compile time)

BTW, you should consider using [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (e.g. a recent GCC 4.8 or 4.9, and compile with `g++ -std=c++11`) then code using a [range-based for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for_loop):

```
for (char c : s) 
   cout << c;
```

and the type inference of C++11 enables you to ask the compiler to guess the type of `c` and code  `for (auto c: s)`

Comment: I think you may be optimistic about what compiler optimizers will do.  In many implementations, `size()` will return the difference between two pointers.  And in many cases, the compiler will not be able to prove that those two pointers are not modified in the loop.  (And in cases like this simple loop, where it should be able to prove it, a lot of compilers won't try hard enough.)  It's simpler to optimize the comparison with a local variable which isn't used anywhere in the loop, other than in the comparison.

Comment: @JamesKanze yet, when I changed `size()` to local variable in my program (Visual Studio compiler), it actually have slown down. I learned to trust optimizers a lot, they can do miracles in compiled code.

Comment: Using any non-inline function is a compiler memory barrier, so I don't think the compiler will optimize `vector.size()`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Remember, that there are requirements on `std` classes in C++ standard. Maybe (and mostly likely) there are some implementation-independent requirements, which allow compilers to optimize size().

Comment: @Spook I don't think so. _The observable behavior of the abstract machine is its sequence of reads and writes to volatile data and 
calls to library I/O functions. Accessing an object designated by a volatile lvalue (3.10), modifying an object, **calling a library I/O
function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.**_

Comment: @Spook In other words, a call to `std::cout.operator<<` could change the size of that vector and the compiler can't prove it does not.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin In all of the implementations I've actually looked at, `vector.size()` (or in this case, `string.size()` _are_ inline, and will usually be inlined.  If you call any functions in the loop which take a reference to the string (even a const reference), of course, and they aren't inlined, the compiler must assume that the might change the pointers in the string.  It also has to prove that the string isn't accessible by any other path, so the pointers can't change.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's true. I am talking about calling `std::cout.operator<<()` between making calls to `vector.size()`. `std::cout.operator<<()` changes the execution environment, all values  must be reloaded from memory.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin That's an interesting point.  If _any_ of the functions which are called on the string (or vector) are not inline, the compiler has to assume that they might have put the `this` pointer in a global variable, which `operator<<` uses to modify the string.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yep, exactly that. There is no such thing as a _small_ or _negligible_ side effect.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin And how does `operator<<` find the vector?  In his specific example (using string, not vector, but that doesn't change anything), the only places the string are known are in the local function and in _its_ member functions.  If all of its member functions which are called are inlined (likely the case), then the compiler can prove that `operator<<` cannot access the object.  (But it's a lot of fairly complicated work, and it wouldn't surprise me that most of the usual compilers don't do it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Same way as `fork()` and `exec()` find all your variables ).

Comment: @JamesKanze Obviously, MSVC is not POSIX compliant and barely C++ compliant )

Comment: @JamesKanze Appears that compilers know about side effects of certain functions, like `gcc` replaces `printf()` with `puts()`. Not sure what happens though if I replace `printf()` with my own version and if it is legit from the standard point of view...

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin `fork()` and `exec()` don't really find my variables; they just copy raw memory.  And they don't modify it; the compiler _can_ assume that a function does not modify local objects whose address has not "escaped" (unless they are declared `volatile`).  Otherwise, it couldn't keep any variables in registers.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin If you've included the necessary standard header, then the compiler can assume that everything declared in it is from the standard library.

Comment: @JamesKanze My point is that `fork()` and `exec()` cause a side effect from standard's point of view. Just like any I/O function or a function that the compiler can't look inside (no definition available).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use types defined in the class. Otherwise the behaviour of the program can be unpredictable.

So instead of

```
string s = "asdf";
int size = s.size();

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
 cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

I would advice to write

```
string s = "asdf";
string::size_type n = s.size();

for ( string::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
 cout << s[i] < <endl;
}
```

There is no big difference between using member function size inside a loop or at first to assign its value to some intermediate variable because the complexity of size() does not depend on the number of elements in a string. Also it is a bad idea to define a variable in a scope where it is not used. So in my point of view this code

```
string s = "asdf";
string::size_type n = s.size();

for ( string::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
 cout << s[i] < <endl;
}
```

is worse than

```
string s = "asdf";

for ( string::size_type i = 0, n = s,size(); i < n; i++ ){
 cout << s[i] < <endl;
}
```

But I would prefer to write simply

```
for ( string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ ){
 cout << s[i] < <endl;
}
```

As for thr reverse loop then it is better to assign the initial value equal to s.size(). It is simialr to how reverse iterators are implemented. So I prefer to write

```
for ( string::size_type i = s.size(); i != 0; i-- ){
 cout << s[i - 1] << endl;
}
```

or as

```
for ( string::size_type i = s.size(); i != 0;  ){
 cout << s[--i] << endl;
}
```

Again take into account that this record

```
for (int i = size - 1; i>= 0; i--){
```

only confuse users when size == 0 and in general case can have unpredictable result if the condition will be cchanged for example as i != 0. Also on the other hand an object of type int can not accomodate all values of type std::string::size_type.

Comment: You should avoid `size_t` for any arithmetic quantities; it's an unsigned type, and unsigned integral types don't work well as numbers in C++.

Comment: And the last works perfectly well if `size` has been declared to have type `int` (which it should be).  With `s.size() - 1`, the conversion to `int` works well in practice (although it is implementation defined).

Comment: @James Kanze I have not understood what you wanted to say and why you wrote your comment to my post. Where did I used suze_t?!

Comment: `string::size_type` is nothing other than a typedef to `size_t`. But I disagree with @JamesKanze, it is not advisable to just use `int`: On 64 bit machines, `size_t` is 8 bytes, but `int` is generally still 4 bytes. And using a too small integer will eventually bite you.

Comment: @cmaster  It is totally wrong! std::string::size_type can be any integral unsigned type. For example size_t can be equivalent to unsigned int while std::string::size_type can be equivalent to unsigned long long.

Comment: @cmaster In the unlikely case that you might have too many elements to represent in an `int`, there's always `ptrdiff_t`.  (Which is what it should have been anyway: the invariant `size() == end() - begin()` is fundamental.)  But in most cases, you should be able to prove that you'll never have more than `INT_MAX` elements.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Only if you use a custom allocator.

Comment: @James Kanze The type ptrdiff_t is implementation-defined. It is not necessary equivalent to int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know.  That's why I said to use it _if_ the number of elements could be larger than `INT_MAX`.  (In practice, of course, it's almost always simpler to just ensure that the number of elements can't be larger than `INT_MAX`.  In a lot of cases, this is ensured by simple rules of the universe: if your data set consists of measurements taken once per second, for example, there's no need to worry.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Any sane implementation of `std::string` will use `size_t` or an equivalent type. `size_t` is the one base type that is defined in connection to the size of the virtual address space. Using any other type to name sizes of memory objects introduces the danger of overflowing too early sometime somewhere. Some equivalent types are `ssize_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `intptr_t`, and `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

As Spook said, you worry too much :)

In C++11 you could do something like this for Q1:

```
std::string myString("foo");
for (char c : myString)
{
    // TODO:
}
```

For reverse iterating, if you'd want to use the same kind of code as above, you'd first have to reverse it like `std::reverse(myString.begin(), myString.end());` and then do the same thing.

Comment: In principle true, but the syntax (of *range-based for loops*) is wrong.

Comment: That would be `for ( char c: myString )`.  Yet another possibility.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch are you sure? both my example and James' compile :). Or were you referring to smth else?

Comment: Your example is _not_ legal C++.  Are you sure you're compiling it as C++, and not some other language?  (It doesn't compile with g++, nor with VC++ if I ask for pure C++, rather than extended C++.)

Comment: @JamesKanze sorry, i'm dumb. VC++ fooled me, I'll correct the answer :D. Really appreciate for pointing it out (dunno why VC "auto corrected" the syntax when I pressed TAB after `for`)

Comment: The non-standard `for each` syntax is supported by C++/CLI, Microsoft's .NET version of C++.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use these two variants:

```
for(size_t i = 0, count = s.size(); i < count; i++) {...}
for(size_t i = s.size(); i--;) {...}
```

Why?
I try to avoid computing the upper bound on each loop iteration, so I need a variable to hold the count for the forward variant.

True, with `std::vector<>` etc. the compiler may be able to optimize it away if I do `for(size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)` (which is probably the more idiomatic way). But if this computation is more expensive and cannot be optimized away (because it's not declared as an `inline` function), unnecessary work will be done if no variable is used to cache the size. I just avoid getting into the habit of writing down unnecessary work and relying on the compiler to remove my nonsense.

Apart from that, I try to keep my code concise. Especially the reverse variant is as small as it can get. Note that it correctly iterates with `i = s.size() - 1` down to `i = 0` by evaluating the condition before the first iteration, which will decrement `i` to the first valid value to use.

---

What should never be done is to do reverse iteration like this:

```
for(size_t i = s.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    cout<<s[i - 1]<<endl;
}
```

This is prone to bugs since it requires the programmer/maintainer to remember that the index is one off throughout the body of the loop.

Comment: Your variant for the reverse loop is very confusing: you modify a value in a conditional, which is _not_ what conditionals are for.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, it's a bit on the tricky side of concise. Nevertheless, it is quite easy to get used to it, and it works correctly for unsigned types: `for(size_t i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)` appears to be correct at first glance, but will silently wrap around. The correct variant would be `for(size_t i = s.size() - 1; i != (size_t)-1; i--)`, and you don't want to read that either.